# Paginator works slow

Tags: django

I work with large database (over 23,000,000 records mssql) and find out that Django Paginator works too slow. So basically is it a problem with database (perhaps, we should do some optimizations in db) or Django Paginator is a bad solution in this case?

Db - MS SQL

paginator = Paginator(qs, max(qs.count()))

Comment: What _is_ `qs`? If it's a heavily filtered queryset, your database will need to first filter all of those records to return the count, and then paginator will do its thing.

Comment: qs is the queryset. It can be simple model.objects.all() and in this case it takes about 2-7 seconds, or it can be heavily filtered and in this case it takes up to 1 minute

Comment: Well, then it's up to your SQL server being slow with a filtered query.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The problem really was that contains-query works very slow especially compared to exact-queries

Comment: Well, yes, if you don't have suitable indices for those fields.